#  how to get one column value in repeater_itemdatabound event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I use repeater in my asp.net application to display records from database. The datasource that binded to repeater are records of a datatable.

How can I get one column value for an item in repeater's itemdatabound event?

I want to get a value of column called 'id'. How to get it in the repeater_itemdatabound event in backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Repeaters ItemDataBound event, you can extract the object bound to the item via the `e.Item.DataItem` property, and do:

```
var item = e.Item.DataItem as MyObject;
if (item.ID > 0)
   //Do something
```

Answer (score 1):

In the item databound event you have access to the event arguments (variable e)
e.Item.DataItem is the record that is currently being bound.  Be sure to cast it as a DataRow or whatever the type is of the item in the collection being bound.

You could access the ID column

```
    Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow = DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, System.Data.DataRow)
    Dim id As Int64 = dr("ID")
```

Comment: You may have to cast it as a `DataRowView`, due to lack of write capabilities on e.Item.DataItem

Comment: Good call.  I mix that up sometimes.